# Backbone Router not working (without parameters)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have

```
var Router1 = Backbone.Router.extend({
     routes: {
         '': 'index',
         'view': 'view1'
     }
});

var router1 = new Router1();
router1.on('route:index', function(){
      alert('Index Page');
});
router1.on('route:view1', function(){
      alert('View 1');
});
```

Following Urls do not do anything

```
http://localhost:8080/App1/index.html        /*should give alert('Index Page')*/
http://localhost:9090/App1/index.html#view   /*should give alert('View1')*/
```

Comment: Did you call `Backbone.history.start()`?

Answer (score 0):

Your router will work for the URLs like

```
http://localhost:8080/
http://localhost:8080/#view
```

Make sure you call `Backbone.history.start()` to route the initial URL.